# How to return the nth value of an <input> in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

If there's only one input element then I can use:

```
$("input").val()
```

I know that `.val()` returns the value of the value attribute of the first matched element.

But what if there are multiple inputs?

Comment: you'd probably have to loop them, or find a way to identify that one more specifically.

Comment: "But what if there are multiple inputs?" What do you *want* to happen when there are multiple inputs? You need to tell us your requirements. If you want to get a *specific* input's value, then get that element by its ID instead of searching for every `input` tag.

Comment: @Maor P please the my answer I think it suits what you're looking for

Comment: @BoffinbraiN I need to assign them to different variables and do all kinds of arithmetic operations with them

Comment: @ChristopheDebove Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the other answers to this question are technically correct, it is very bad practice to design your forms and scripts this way. It is fragile and hard to maintain. If the number of input fields, or the ordering of those fields ever changes, your code will break. For example, if you later decided to add a search box to your website's template, the indexes of all your input fields would increase by one and break everything.

I would suggest you take a name or ID-based approach to your form fields, so that each one serves a clear purpose and can be easily found by jQuery. If your form fields already have names (and they should, if you're using a traditional HTML form using GET or POST) then you can use those. You may also give them unique IDs.

```
<input name="Input1" id="MyInput1" value="" >
<input name="Input2" id="MyInput2" value="" >
```

```
var input1 = $("#MyInput1").val(); // Get by ID
var input2 = $("[name=Input2]").val(); // Get by input's name
```

If you have *multiple forms* per page, then the best practice changes again slightly, but I'll elaborate on that only if you need me to.

I hope this helps you see the bigger picture so you can develop better forms.

Comment: Agreed. My answer is very specific to the question of getting the value by ordinal, but a good design should assign meaningful unique identifiers to key elements.

Comment: Simple and effective.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the css pseudo class `:nth-child` then retrieve the first element
https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child

```
var element = $("input:nth-child(5n)").first();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('input').each(function(i, inputElement){
     console.log($(inputElement).val());
 })
```

the second parameter is not the value its the inputElement, you need to wrap it again in $() to work with .val()

Answer (score 1):

In the case of multiple matches, jQuery will return a (zero based) array of matching elements.

So if you specifically want to access the value of the 2nd input element, you can do so like this:

```
$("input")[1].value
```

Note that you're accessing an array of DOM elements here, not jQuery objects, so you can't use `.val()` but have to use the element's value property.

To get a jQuery object of the nth element, you can use jQuery's :eq() selector like so:

```
$("input:eq(1)").val()
```

https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/

Answer (score 0):

Given a form, this will help you get all the input element of that form and  then you can just get their value.

```
$("form").each(function(){
$(this).find(':input') //<-- Should return all input elements in that specific form.
});
```

Answer (score 0):

An easy way is to loop to find each value:

```
 $('input').each(function(i, value){
      // i = index value for each input
      // value = actual value 
 })
```

Comment: // value = actual value is not true